# How to add more place in here map using c#?

Tags: c#, here-api, here-launcher

i just try here launcher to add place using this code:-

```
ExploremapsShowPlaceTask showPlace = new ExploremapsShowPlaceTask(); 
showPlace.Location = new GeoCoordinate((Double)watcher.Position.Location.Latitude,   (Double)watcher.Position.Location.Longitude); 
showPlace.Zoom = 40; 
showPlace.Title = "My Place"; 
showPlace.Show();
```

but it just cannot add one more place, how to add more place using that code?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the [API Reference](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/Lumia/maps-and-navigation/here-launchers/here-launchers-api-reference.html), the `ExploremapsShowPlaceTask` is for moving the map to an individual place:

> The `ExploremapsShowPlaceTask` allows you to start the Maps
>   application with the map centered to a place shown in the map.

What you need instead is either the `ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask` or the `ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask` e.g.:

> The `ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask` allows you to start the Maps
>   application with the search view.

or

> The `ExploremapsExplorePlacesTask` allows you to start the Maps
>   application where the nearby places of interest are shown.

Use something like this:

```
ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask searchMap = new ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask();
searchMap.Location = new GeoCoordinate(60.35, 24.60);
searchMap.SearchTerm = "Hotel";
searchMap.Show();
```

Comment: thanks for your respond... but i want create custom place manually with data i have like using that code.. because if i used "ExploremapsSearchPlacesTask" POI results that appear in the HERE Map is not complete as the data I want to show.

Comment: The HERE launchers does not provide the functionality you are asking for, thus either you use the functionality available, or you look for alternative ways on achieving your goal.

Comment: As the name suggests, the HERE Maps launchers fire up the standard capabilities of the HERE Maps app. If you're after a custom map you'll need the [Maps API for Windows Phone](https://github.com/nokia-developer/maps-samples)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not show multiple custom places with HERE launchers API, though you could indeed use the other functionality of the API for showing places that are from Nokia PLACEs database.

Thus, If you really need to show multiple places on a map view, then you can not use HERE launchers, instead you should use the Maps API directly, and have you own logic on showing the map and all required places inside of it.

Comment: thanks for your info sir..
but is there any other way to use here launcher like i want using here launcher to show multiple custom places?

Comment: No there are no other functionality available with the API than what is specified in the documentation for the API.